Harnack inequality of normalized Ricci flow on surface
I want to understand the mean of green line in bottom picture, which is from The Ricci flow on surfaces (237- 262 of this).
The $r=\int R d\mu/\int d\mu$ is the average of scalar curvature.
My English is not good. I think the green line may be understand as

It follows from the maximum principle that
$$
Q\ge -r e^{rt}/(e^{rt}-1)
$$
no matter how negative $Q$ is to start, by comparing to the solution of the ordinary differential equation. Therefore, we would get $Q$ were constant in space.

I feel the if in picture below may be a typo. But as my above understand, I don't know why $Q$ were constant in space.



